# display all records in single page in report telerik viewer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, report, reporting, records, viewer

i want to display whole records in telerik Report Viewer in single page. This report does't contain paging.  How to display all records in single page in report viewer in asp.,

Comment: have you tried this.yourlabelsGroup.GroupKeepTogether = GroupKeepTogether.All;

Comment: i had used ., but the report viewer goes 2 page the first page should be empty and the 2rd page has all the record. i want only one page ie first page itself display all the records.,